# Typo3 6.1, Issue in the proper generation of the thumbnail images for the uploaded images

Tags: php, image-processing, typo3, thumbnails, typo3-6.1.x

I am new to Typo3. I am using 6.1 version of it. I am using Unix system.

When ever I upload image from the front end or from the back-end, it generates the thumbnail image as 'No Thumb Generated!' instead of generating the thumbnail for the actual image uploaded.

I have surfed through the Internet and found out various suggestions like :

1) To make sure that the ImageMagik is already installed and test the image tests from the Back-end Install tool.

2) To make sure that there is no space before or after the PHP opening and closing tags for my realurl_conf.php and LocalConfiguration.php inside typo3conf folder.

But I have checked those suggestions and they are already as expected.

Below is some of the required code snippets that can help some one to assist me with the proper solution for the issue.

#### LocalConfiguration.php

```
return array(
 ....,
 'GFX' => array(
    'gdlib_png' => 1,
    'im_combine_filename' => 'composite',
    'im_imvMaskState' => '1',
    'im_path' => '/usr/local/im6/bin/',
    'im_path_lzw' => '/usr/local/im6/bin/'),

 'SYS' => array(
    'compat_version' => '6.1',
    'devIPmask' => 'SOME_VALID_IP_HERE',
    'enableDeprecationLog' => 0,
    'encryptionKey' => 'SOME_KEY_HERE',
    'setDBinit' => 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'',
    'sitename' => 'SOME_NAME_HERE',
    'sqlDebug' => '0',
))
```

Please let me know how can I solve the issue.

Please let me know if anything more required from my end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your setup should be fine, have you tried the test section in the Install-Tool? Are the settings »$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[GFX][image_processing]« and »$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[GFX][thumbnails]« on (without them you are able to use ImageMagic, but the backend wont generate thumbnails tough)?

Comment: @pixelbrackets, I have checked and those configurations are enabled.
But still its not working.